# How do you read the legs of a multileg order using QuickFix in C#?

Tags: c#, trading, quickfix

When processing a `QuickFix44.NewOrderMultileg` message in C#, how do you extract the details of the legs?

The only documentation I've found so far seems to apply only to market data and/or be wildly out of date:
http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/csharp/repeating_groups_2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as you have done in the application, but you have to go a little deeper.

```
NewOrderMultileg -> InstrumentLeg/LegSipulations and other groups and fields.
```

Get the count of legs present in the message by reading **NoLegs**. Then iterate over the message reading the groups one by one.

The components in the message may be in a group or single. Whenever you find the suffix **Grp** expect multiple groups. Refer [here](http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXimate3.0/) for clarification.

Do not write the same piece of code multiple times, make a loop. You don't know how many groups are there in the message.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= groupCount; ++i)
{
    message.getGroup(i, group);
    group.get(MDEntryType);
    group.get(MDEntryPx);
    group.get(MDEntrySize);
    group.get(orderID);
    /* Do other stuff */
}
```

For components in the message, one for each leg, read the component in that loop as well.

Comment: What is the declaration of `group` in your example?  And what if the order has, say, both a LegOrdGrp and an UndInstrmtGrp, how do you distinguish between them?

Comment: @Eric - group is NewOrderMultileg::NoLegs, this is the group,**not the number of legs**. For 2nd question, you iterate over the **full message after reading the number of groups** for the specific groups i.e. NewOrderMultileg::NoUnderlyings.

Comment: +1 for your answer. However, if I'm not wrong, repeating groups are not zero-based (unfortunately), then your loop must go in [1, groupCount]

Comment: @Luca Martini - Yes it should be 1, I overlooked the fact. Thanks, rectified it.

Comment: @DumbCoder - The class `QuickFix.NoLegs` derives from `IntField` and (in the case of my 2-leg order) has the value 2. So it seems like I should write `groupCount = order.getNoLegs().Value`. But I don't see any method that returns a `Group`, nor any nested type within NewOrderMultiLeg that derives from `Group`, and the constructors for `Group` are opaque. So how do I get something to use as the second argument for `getGroup`? Could you expand your example to be a full function, say `PrintLegRefIds( NewOrderMultiLeg order ) { /* print out LegRefId for each leg */ }` ?

Comment: @DumbCoder -  Ah, I see now.  You get `groupCount` by calling `var groupCount = order.getNoLegs().getValue()`.  Meanwhile, you get `group` by allocating with `var group = new NewOrderMultiLeg.NoLegs();`.  It's confusing because the names are so similar.